# How to turn off csrf in tastypie post?

Tags: csrf, tastypie

When I have session authentication on, according to:
https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html
I need csrf.
How can I temporarily turn it off?
I see something like https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html?highlight=csrf#determining-format-via-url
I think I need to override another method other than wrap_view and do nothing but have @csrf_exempt.
Google really did not return anything to me.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem and I solved it with override the method SessionAutentication.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by creating a subclass of Authentication like @UnLiMiTeD said:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie.authentication import Authentication

class BaseAuthentication(Authentication):

    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        return request.user.is_authenticated()

class YourResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authentication = BaseAuthentication()
```